Get bootpd & bootpc to talk to each other successfully
The current Debian bootpc and bootpd (from bootp) do not appear to actually work together in today's Linux kernel environment. There seems to be a / problem; bootpd sends the replies as unicast UDP packets to the as-yet-unconfigured IP address. The client's kernel then drops them w/out delivering to the bootpc client's socket, b/c that IP address is not (yet) a valid local address on the host.
How did this ever work?

Is there a kernel parameter or other modification that can get the kernel to give these packets to the bootpc process?
Is there a configuration for bootpd that will get it to use all 1's or all 0's destination IP addresses instead of the as-yet-unconfigured client IP unicast address?

We have a prospective customer with a large bootp non-DHCP infrastructure. Old-school bootp support is one of their requirements.
Issue Details

bootpd sends its reply packets as unicast packets to the bootpc client's MAC address, using a destination IP address value of the address that it is also in the payload telling the client to configure itself with.
The kernel then drops these packets, rather than deliver them to the bootpc process that requested them.
bootpc has correctly opened a listening socket for 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* (see netstat output below)
I've verified this analysis in several ways:

I've run tcpdump and I can see the replies getting to the NIC
I've run dropwatch and see the packets getting dropped with a reason of IPINADDRERROR, which basically means "invalid IP address"
I can trick bootpd into using 0.0.0.0 as the destination IP address by omitting and actual IP assignment; when I do this, bootpc gets the responses and processes them. However this doesn't help b/c then the client doesn't get an IP address
I've tried adding the IP address to the interface while bootpc is making requests. Once I add it, the next reply gets to the process.


I've also tried the bootpc --serverbcast option. This fails for a similar reason:

bootpd sends the replies to the subnet broadcast address (e.g. 10.0.43.255)
Since the IP address & subnet mask aren't configured on an interface yet, the kernel has no reason to consider this a valid address for itself.


Here is our current bootptab configuration:

.vs-default:\
  :sm=255.255.254.0:\
  :gw=10.0.42.1:\
  :ds=10.0.42.1:\
  :hn:
client-ad02-vs:\
  ht=1:\
  ha=0xea4a1fad0002:\
  ip=10.0.42.31:\
  tc=.vs-default:

Netstat output showing bootpc's listening socket:
$ sudo netstat -unlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           2295/bootpc         

Hacky Workaround
I've come up with a work-around that feels hacky. In particular, I think it leverages an unintended behavior, maybe we can't count on it to work in the future:

the iptables conntrack module has a match ctstate with a value of DNAT.
This can be used to accept packets that have an unrecognized destination IP address
I don't think it is intended to match arbitrary DST IP's:

It can only be used with packets that were NAT'd by the same host's kernel
I think its purpose is to match packets that have had their address rewritten (which we are not doing), but it is a "cheap" implementation that ignores the NAT mapping table instead of verifying that there is an entry that matches this specific packet.
I'm concerned this will either be removed, or re-written to be less promiscuous in the future
To get this to work, I have to port-map these packets to their existing DST port, just to get NAT connection state data onto the packet, otherwise --ctstate DNAT doesn't apply to the packet.



Background/Due Diligence

Our testbed is using is Debian 12 on Linux 6.1.0.
Our testbed hosts are from UTM Debian 12 off-the-shelf VM images
bootpd has very few cli options, none of which involve replies, ports or addresses. The man page doesn't mention "broadcast" or "unicast", and references to "address" or "destination" are few & not relevant.
Our actual product is Debian 12 on a custom Linux 5.19.9 kernel (and behaves the same way)
IP connectivity is fully working between the testbed client and server
bootpc refuses to send requests unless the following are true:

There is no routable IP address already on the interface  (169.254/16 is allowed, although I've tried it without too)
There is a 0/0 default route pointing to the interface where the bootp server is expected

Otherwise it says network unreachable
Note: specifying --dev <iface> on the bootpc command line doesn't help with this




I'm still working on evaluating bootptab configuration options to see if there are any that affect this. Haven't found a good reference for them, the man bootptab man page is very terse about them.

Alternate Workaround
I've been able to get this to work with a less convoluted iptables solution: I added a NAT rule that matches UDP port 68 (bootpc), and maps the destination IP address to 255.255.255.255 (and keeps the same UDP port).
This works, but I consider this hacky. Clearly this isn't how the protocol is meant to work, so I'd prefer a "real" solution if possible.


There seems to be a / problem; bootpd sends the replies as unicast UDP packets to the as-yet-unconfigured IP address. The client's kernel then drops them w/out delivering to the bootpc client's socket, b/c that IP address is not (yet) a valid local address on the host.
How did this ever work?

DHCP behaves the same way; most DHCP clients, and I expect also BOOTP clients, use raw sockets to receive whole IP packets before the usual kernel processing (as well as to send IP packets while not yet having any IP address to send them from). The client software itself builds the full IP and UDP header when sending the discover or request, and then uses BPF¹ to filter inbound packets instead of the usual bind()-to-local-port.
(Among other things, this also bypasses iptables inbound filtering and UDP checksum fixups.)

Is there a kernel parameter or other modification that can get the kernel to give these packets to the bootpc process?

The client should be rewritten to use raw sockets (AF_PACKET, PF_LINK, or similar).
For example, systemd-networkd uses socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, ...) like in this source. The dhcpcd client uses AF_LINK on some systems, AF_PACKET on others, and likewise filters packets using BPF¹ instead of having the kernel do it.
To make things simpler, some parts could be handled via libpcap.
¹ (This is "classic" BPF – Berkeley Packet Filter – rather than modern eBPF, so it is not Linux-specific and doesn't require any unusual features.)

Is there a configuration for bootpd that will get it to use all 1's or all 0's destination IP addresses instead of the as-yet-unconfigured client IP unicast address?

The server should honor a "wants broadcast" flag in the BOOTP or DHCP request. Debian's bootpc client sets it when you pass --serverbcast (because it doesn't use raw sockets apparently):
  /* Server needs to broadcast for me to see it */
  if (broadcast || givenhwaddr)
    bootp_xmit->bp_flags |= htons(BPFLAG_BROADCAST);

But the bootp server only honors this flag when compiled with the DHCP option that Debian patches into it:
#ifdef DHCP
    /*
     * This code is placed here, because otherwise the siaddr
     * will not be found...
     */
    if (ntohs(bp->bp_flags) & 0x8000 && bp->bp_giaddr.s_addr==0)
        dst.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
#endif

If you are trying to integrate your new Bootp server into a network existing Bootp clients, then ISC dhcpd might work better for you as it seems to have a Bootp compatibility mode. (Yes, the one that's now EOL, but at least it's less EOL than Debian's bootp server – which seems to have been last touched in 1995).
Likewise, if you're trying to make your client system work with existing Bootp infrastructure, consider whether you could instead use some DHCP client in Bootp mode.

Thank you - so the basic answer is something like "No, this never worked." I haven't found a DHCP client with true bootp capability yet, but we did find that udhcpc "works." It has a static default lease time built in, which prevents it from chocking when there is no lease time offered, and ultimately it does receive the reply and configure the interface.
